# Show a message and assign value to a field in an onchange method

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to write an onchange that returns a message and updates a value at the same time. So far it displays the message but the field remains the same. The code I have is:

```py
@api.onchange('changed_field')
def my_onchange_method(self):    
    if self.other_field:
        self.changed_field=False
        raise Warning('Some message.')
```

I think my mistake is in the way of sending the message, could anyone tell me how to achieve this in odoo 9? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're raising the **builtin** Warning exception, which is probably why the field isn't updated (I think the changes are rolled back when the exception is raised).

Try this instead :

```py
@api.onchange('changed_field')
def my_onchange_method(self):    
    if self.other_field:
        self.changed_field = False
        return {
            'warning': {
                'title': 'TITLE OF THE WARNING MESSAGE BOX',
                'message': 'YOUR WARNING MESSAGE',
            }
        }
```

I can confirm this works at least for odoo 8. It will probably work for odoo 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
def onchange_amount_paid(self, cr, uid, ids, amount_paid, context=None):


res = {'value':{}}

if amount_paid:

if fee_type==1 and amount_paid<70:

warning = { 'title': ("Warning"), 'message': ('registration account minimum payment is 70'), }

return {'value': res.get('value',{}), 'warning':warning} 

return {'value': res.get('value',{})}
```